Chaining async class methods, Where and Why does the Scope Change?
I wrote a class module that has async methods, and now im trying to chain the methods using .then()
the scope of 'this' changes somewhere along the line and i then have to bind the function back to its instance to get the proper scope back.
class.js
class Asdf {
  #asdf;
  constructor(){
    this.#asdf = 'asdf'
  }
  async funcOne(){
    // h.funcOne().then // works fine
    return this.#asdf
  }
  async funcTwo(a){
    // .then(h.funcTwo) // this.funcThree becomes undefined?
    // where does the scope change??
    var x = await this.funcThree(a)
    return x
  }
  async funcThree(a){
    return a
  }
}
module.exports = Asdf

script.js
var h = new (require('./class.js'));

h.funcOne().then(h.funcTwo) // scope is changed, code breaks, claiming undefined

h.funcOne().then(h.funcTwo.bind(h)) // works because we re-bind the scope

// Where and Why does the Scope Change??

Why does the scope change using .then? and can I prevent it?

The scope changes when you pass a reference to a function directly. You can avoid it the exact way you've already done (with bind) or wrapping in an (arrow) function.

Does this answer your question? How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?

@trincot No, not in the slightest.

I don't think you have read it then. this is determined by how a function is called. As you pass the function for the internals of Promise to call it, you don't control it. It is called without this context. The common misunderstanding is that this is somehow linked to where a function is defined as method. All this is explained in detail in that Q&A, with exercises, ...etc. See especially the section "Calls without base reference" in the accepted answer.

By the way, this has nothing to do with "scope".

@trincot that links to a huge wall of text, in which i am still trying to find what your talking about. you may as well have linked me to the official documentation and told me good luck finding the snippet i barely described.

@trincot, if you would place this comment into an answer, i could accept it and you get points for it.

I know it is a lot of text, but I assure you that if you absorb all of it, you'll never ever have any question about JavaScript's this anymore. ever. It is worth it.

This is not about scope in the literal definition.  It's about the binding of the this value when a function is called in different ways.
The issue is that when you pass h.funcTwo as a function argument, it reaches into the h object and grabs a reference to funcTwo and passed JUST a reference to that function that will be called without any reference to h and will not be associated with h at all.  That means that this inside that call to funcTwo() will be undefined because it wasn't called as h.funcTwo().
So, as you found, can use .bind() to instead pass a function stub that will call it as h.funcTwo() rather than just as funcTwo().
You can see a simpler example here:


"use strict";

const x = {
    f: function() { console.log(this)},
    g: "it's me",
};

x.f();    // properly logs the x object

let y = x.f;
y();      // logs undefined since the binding to x was lost
          // and f() was called all by itself without 
          // any reference to x

 let z = x.f.bind(x);      // properly logs the x object
 z();     



